# Hanging a heavy edgeless mirror so that it tilts down

Tags: drywall, walls, studs, mirror

I have a mirror similar to this:

[image]

I'd like to hang it like this:

[image]

...where the angle can be easily adjusted whenever I'd like.

I'd like to figure out how to simply, cheaply, and securely (living in CA - earthquakes may strike again) achieve this.  I was considering using french cleats like this on the bottom edge of the mirror:

[image]

... and then some D-rings up top to control the angle.  But I don't know if the "lean" of the cleat will damage the wall at the bottom if I do this.

Another alternative is to just build a thin shelf with a small lip, but I'm trying to go as minimal / unobtrusive as possible here.  I'd prefer not to see any hardware.

Comment: @jsotola I don't want to build a bunch of wedge-shaped boxes for different angles.  This will be used for photography so some degree of configurability is what I'm after.

Comment: perhaps you could use a TV mount of some type

Comment: @jsotola I'm not finding your comments to be very constructive.  Have you read my post?

Comment: yes, i read it ... just throwing out an alternate idea

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to tilt down unless you're interested in seeing the top of your head. Most full length mirrors are set flush against a wall several inches above the floor. You can still see your feet due to the angle of your eyes relative to the mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how well it is for earthquakes, but for better security, I'd go with hinges at the bottom, instead of cleats. That would provide less chance of mirror jumping from its position during a minor earthquake, and also wouldn't bruise the wall during angle change, if the hinge is hanged at the very bottom of frame.

For top I would go with with D-ring free-angled bolt anchors in the wall, something on these lines:

[image: image courtesy of https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200658591_200658591]

, with D-rings at the top of the mirror frame (as you said), and appropriate thickness chains linking the two. This would also provide for easy change of mirror angle -- just control the angle by inserting pins or similar fasteners in appropriate links of the chains.

As a bonus, nothing should be visible from front of the mirror.